# Kubernetes nfs volumes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm referring to this [1] document about creating nfs mounts on kubernetes. But I have couple of issues to be clarified.

1. What is meant by privileged containers?
2. How can I set allow-privileged true of a kubernetes setup installed on bare metal ubuntu machine? I setup it using kebe-up.sh script.

[1] http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/examples/nfs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/pods.md#privileged-mode-for-pod-containers

That refers to the corresponding field in the yaml: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/types.go#L2089

And it should be on per the document in 1.1 (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b9cfab87e33ea649bdd13a1bd243c502d76e5d22/cluster/saltbase/pillar/privilege.sls#L2, you can confirm by creating the pod and running kubectl describe like the docs says).